# Does iOS support view-based Table Views?

Tags: ios, tableview, nstableviewcell

Does iOS support view-based tables, in addition to the classic cell-based tables?  It appears this new capability is only on the Mac (OS X v 10.7).  Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "view-based tables".

Comment: In Mac OS X v7 Table Views were redesigned and support using views as individual cells (view-based tables) as opposed to the requirement of being a subclass of NSCell.  As pointed out to me by Brian below, I wasn't reading deep enough in the iOS UITableViewCell reference doc since this capability is already present in iOS.   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with View Based Cells, but from looking into it it looks like this was needed because the NSCell does not extend NSView.  But, in iOS, UITableViewCell does extend UIView.  So, I think View Based Table Cells are not a new concept in iOS since they've alawys been that way.

NSCell - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html

UITableViewCell - http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Absolutely. This is a case of OS X catching up with iOS, not the other way around.

Comment: OK - yes, I see that you can access the UITableViewCell's "contentView" property and apply subViews to that.  Thank you!